# Copy command/search history to clipboard

Tags: vim

I'm trying to insert the commands

Copy Command History to clipboard `q::%y`
Copy Search History to clipboard  `q/:%y`

in a vimscript doing this:

```
:normal q::%y
:normal q/:%y
```

but it doesn't copy anything
Why?

(It works fine when I do it manually (`q::%y`  `q/:%y`))

Comment: I have no idea why that doesn't work. Strange. This isn't a full answer because I don't know the *why*, but you could do `:call feedkeys("q::%y\<CR>:q\<CR>")` instead.

Comment: It works on the commandline but not in my vimscript.  Error: `call feedkeys("q::%y`   missing quote - Tried to double the backslashes but that doesn't work.

Comment: What command did you try that gave that error?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem `:call feedkeys("q::%y\<CR>:q\<CR>")` well not totally true, I include this in another command `call myscript(":call feedkeys('q::%y\<CR>:q\<CR>')")`

Comment: How about `:call feedkeys("q::%y<C-v><CR>:q<C-v><CR>")<cr>`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem, doesn't seem to work. The cursor stays in insert mode without copying anything.

Comment: found it! :)  `call feedkeys("q::%y\<lt>CR>:q\<lt>CR>")` Thanks for your help.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is because `:normal! q:` doesn't work, probably because most multiletter normal commands are handled ad-hoc in the code. Should probably report this as a bug.

Comment: @Reman You should post and accept a self answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
nnoremap <Leader>r q::%y<cr>
```

and to close the window after:

```
nnoremap <Leader>r q::%y<cr>:q<cr>
```